# Eclipse plugin development: How to include another project?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing a Eclipse plugin. From this plugin I want to instantiate classes from another project that I have developed. I added this project to the build path, but nevertheless, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myPackage.myClass
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
```

I'm sure that I have to add the refernce to this project somewere else, but where? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dependent plugin (as Francis suggested), or add it as a library jar. Both methods are described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ#I.27m_using_third_party_jar_files_and_my_plug-in_is_not_working).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding a link to the other projects source folder as source folder to my project. However, I do not know whether this is the best possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your other project a plugin and then add it to your original plugin's manifest as a dependent plugin.

Comment: A plugin project is just a java project with a special MANIFEST.MF (and extra eclipse builders).  It would still work fine when deployed as a java-only jar.